# Can I kill/catch legendary animals only once?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I killed the legendary bear and the legendary coyote so far. Now I wanted to start catching some legendary fish.

But I wonder, can I kill/catch all the legendary animals only once per type? Or do they respawn, have multiple random occurrences or exist several times in different locations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only catch each one once, and they're not randomly located but they are always in the same region, as indicated on the map of legendary animals.

Comment: If Artur dies while carrying normal pelts on the back of the horse, the pelts are lost (happend sometimes to me). I wonder if the legendary pelt is also lost in that case. Because if i cant kill the legendary again, i would always travel to trapper first, so i can unlock every extra there during my playthrough...

Comment: @kl78 the legendary pelts are never lost, they get automatically teleported to the Trapper if you lose them. You miss out on the money you'd get for selling them, but you can still craft with them in this case.

Comment: And if you catch and lose a legendary fish, they go back into the water and are re-catchable.